# powershell date dynamic for unzip file

Tags: powershell

Im trying to utilse date with wild card in unzipping a file. So far Im able to just have *.zip and be able to unzip the file, but I want to add dynamic date as well. So far I have this

`Get-ChildItem S:\IT21_TCN_Reports\*$date.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd")*.zip | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath S:\IT21_TCN_Reports\`

But adding the date in the string not working. Im not good with powershell, so im sure what I have is wrong. If I can get some help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: Change your $date.tostring("yadayada") to $(get-date -format yyyy_MM_dd)
and just to be sure, surround your paths with double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing that:

```
$date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)  # for demo use yesterdays date

# create a filter using the date
$filter = '*{0:yyyy_MM_dd}*.zip' -f $date  # --> "*2020_04_08*.zip"
Get-ChildItem -Path 'S:\IT21_TCN_Reports' -Filter $filter -File | Expand-Archive -DestinationPath 'S:\IT21_TCN_Reports'
```

The `-f` Format operator adds the date in the specified manner to the template string, overwriting the placeholder `{0}`